# Reload the component in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am using angular 4. I am struck with one issue in UI.I have a emp1 First and emp2.If I select emp1, it will load the details of employee 1. If i select emp 2, All the form fields are same and it will load the details of employee 2.

URL for First is: http://localhost:4200/empDetails/1

URL for Second is: http://localhost:4200/empDetails/2

Only the id has changed in URL and route. The problem is When change from emp1 to emp2 URL is changed, But HTML is not refreshed. Same values are displayed(whatever value displayed for emp1). It is not getting refreshed.

I googled and tried the below approach. BUt it is not working.In my onInit method,

```
this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
                 this.empId = params['id'];
            //below get method is get all the details based on emp id.
                 this.getEmpData(this.empId);     
                });
```

OnDropdown change:

```
dropdownChange(){
        this.router.navigate(['/empDetails/' + this.empId]);
    }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: any error as activated route should work

Comment: That's working as intented. When only a router parameter changes, the route will not reload the component. You need a custom reload strategy. There are already several questions about that.

Comment: In your dropdown change event why don't you just reload your employee data using getempdata() instead of reloading the whole page?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not trying to reloading entire page. I want reload the only the form data based on emp id. It is not getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

```
const _self = this;
this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
                 _self.empId = params['id'];
                 _self.getEmpData(_self.empId);     
                });
```

and still you are facing the same issue then,
inject a `ChangeDetectorRef` in your component and call its method `detectChanges` manually on value change.

for example:

```
constructor(private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
      const _self = this;
      this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
                 _self.empId = params['id'];
                 _self.getEmpData(_self.empId);
                  _self.cd.detectChanges();
                });
}
```